# Limit my player from moving to much in x-direction

Tags: swift, width, coordinates, skspritenode

In the image you can see my boat in my game. I have made it so that it can't move in the y-direction, only in the x-direction. Now, I want to limit the boat so that it can't move out of the water instead of as it is now where it can move the whole width of the screen.  How can I make this possible?

Here is an image of the game:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e1ZX.png

class GameScene: SKScene {

```
var boat = SKSpriteNode()

var bg = SKSpriteNode()

var touched:Bool = false

var location = CGPoint.zero




override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


    boat.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)

    self.addChild(boat)

    let bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg.png")

    let moveBGAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -bgTexture.size().width), duration: 5)
    let shiftBGAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: bgTexture.size().width), duration: 0)
    let moveBGForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBGAnimation, shiftBGAnimation]))


    var i: CGFloat = 0


    while i < 3 {

        bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)

        bg.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: bgTexture.size().width * i)

        bg.size.height = self.frame.height

        bg.run(moveBGForever)

        self.addChild(bg)

        i += 1

        bg.zPosition = -1
    }


    let boatTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "boat.png")

    boat = SKSpriteNode(texture: boatTexture)

    boat.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY - 300)

    boat.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: boatTexture.size().height / 2)

    boat.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    self.addChild(boat)

}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    touched = true
    for touch in touches {
    location = touch.location(in:self)

    }
}


override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    touched = false


}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        location = touch.location(in: self)
    }
}



override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered

    if (touched) {
        moveNodeToLocation()
    }
}

func moveNodeToLocation() {
    // Compute vector components in direction of the touch
    var dx = location.x - boat.position.x
    // How fast to move the node. Adjust this as needed
    let speed:CGFloat = 0.25
    // Scale vector
    dx = dx * speed
    boat.position = CGPoint(x:boat.position.x+dx, y: -300)
}
```

}

Comment: show some code, it is simple to do what you want to do, but at least give some code to work with

Comment: Now, I added my code to the text!

Answer (score 0):

You calculate your future position of the boat so you can also check `x` is within the bounds you specify, in `moveNodeToLocation`:

```
let newPosition = boat.position.x + dx
if newPosition > 20 && newPosition < 300 {
    boat.position = CGPoint(x: newPosition, y: -300)
}
```

The limit values here are only for example, you can dynamically calculate them of course if needed, imagine `bgTexture.size` will be useful here and may even vary by level etc